# adding wait bar to matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created MatLab GUI and it execute matlab script by clicking button on GUI.

now I want method for showing time consuming for run of that script

following code shows how I did that so far

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
run('resizeingDONTDELETE.m');
end
```

I find a code for show wait bar but it is not worked!!!!

```
h = waitbar(0,'Please wait...');
steps = 1000;
for step = 1:steps
run('resizeingDONTDELETE.m');
    waitbar(step / steps)
end
close(h)
```

here I want the results as follow,

- when push button is clicked wait button should be open and should
  show time as zero
- time should be increased with time taken to executing the script
- after executing wait bar should be disappered

can anyone help me .......

Comment: your `waitbar` call should be somewhere inside `resizeingDONTDELETE.m`, if it has a for loop, not outside.

Comment: what happened it contain no of for loops

Comment: how can it modify in order to display the prograss (I mean when half of script is executed then bar remain at it middle point and like wise)

Comment: see my answer, it becomes too long for a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `waitbar` is useful if your script is divided to some intermediate steps (not necessarily a for loop), where you can indicate a progress in (or before) each intermediate step. In pseudo-code, assuming you have 4 intermediate steps:

- Main Script

  - waitbar(0/4)
  - do intermediate step 1
  - waitbar(1/4)
  - do intermediate step 2
  - waitbar(2/4)
  - do intermediate step 3
  - waitbar(3/4)
  - do intermediate step 4
  - waitbar(4/4)

Otherwise, if your script is a 'black box' which starts and terminates without giving you access to some intermediate steps - you cannot use `waitbar` in a useful way.

Comment: can you please help me to represent that with respect to time (I mean that the time taken for the process in second/minute/hours)

Comment: In order to represent time, you will need to know (at least approximately) the total time `t_total`, so you can write at the start `tt=tic;` and then `waitber(toc(tt) / t_total)`

Comment: will it show the time (I mean time in number {let at 1s as 00 00 01, at 2s as 00 00 02 and finally 00 t_total 55 (assume) like wise})

Comment: No, it will show the fraction of time out of total time, that is the full waitbar corresponds to value of `1`. If you need the time, why not just `printf` the time?

Comment: if it is so then how can i print it on the same wait bar   `waitbar(toc(tt) / t_total);printf(tt);
close(h)`   is it possible

Comment: how can i give value for t_total (i mean that in second or minute )

Comment: You can use the `waitbar(x,h,'updated message')` syntax in order to set the string message to the time you want. Please read the doc entry of `waitbar`, it's all there.